# ¿Cómo obtener el numero de los valores repetidos en una lista y su descripción con LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Que tal, tengo declarada una lista en vb.net de la siguiente manera

```
Dim ListID As New List(Of String)()
```

la cual la lleno dinámicamente.

Quiero obtener con LINQ cual es el número de veces que se repite un registro en la lista y el nombre del registro.

Comment: Es sobre vb .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad es que acostumbrado a la flexibilidad de los tipos anonimos en C#, me ha costado trasladar este codigo de C# a Vb.net. Asi que es posible que en VB.Net haya una solucion mas logica si tener que usar una clase intermedia, pero como no suelo usarlo no estoy muy seguro. Lo que necesitas primero es una clase donde almacenar los resultados:

```
Private Class Resultados
    Public Nombre As String
    Public Total As Integer
End Class
```

Luego la consulta en si no es complicada. Tienes que agrupar para juntar todos los String iguales y luego seleccionarlos dentro de esta nueva clase contando el numero de ellos que hay en cada grupo:

```
Dim resultado = ListID.GroupBy(Function(x) x).Select(Function(y) New Resultados() With {
        .Nombre = y.Key,
        .Total = y.Count()})
```

Para consultar los resultados:

```
For Each res As Resultados In resultado
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} se repite {1} veces", res.Nombre, res.Total))
Next
```

Comment: VB.NET igual permite [tipos anonimos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531249(v=vs.100).aspx) :)

Comment: @NaCl si. Pero una vez realizada la consulta, no hay una manera sencilla de acceder a las propiedades de ese tipo anonimo. En c# simplemente podrias hacer `resultado.First().Nombre`. En Vb.net no es posible acceder a ninguno de los resultados, o yo no he sido capaz :)

Comment: @NaCl mira [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874746/how-can-i-get-a-value-of-a-property-from-an-anonymous-type). Necesitas Reflection para acceder a las propiedades, lo que parece ridiculo la verdad.

Comment: La verdad no me había fijado en eso :O

Comment: @NaCl yo como siempre programo en C# tampoco. Me ha sorpendido la verdad :)

Comment: @Pikoh Me ha servido justo para lo que quería, gracias!!.